# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object,

Tags: python, encoding, byte, decode

```
with open((item[1], 'wb'), encoding='utf-8') as imge1:
                
                rttd = imge1.write()
                print(rttd)
```

I am trying to access this file but  I have no idea how to, Ive tried using decode and encoding outside the 'with open' line to try and get rid of the tuple but then i get a unicode error. Below is the error when i write this code above

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple in Python
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the first two arguments of `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in `open((item[1], 'wb'), encoding='utf-8')` the arguments 0 and 1 are inside of a tuple (e. G. (1, 2, 3)).instead use `open(item[1], 'wb', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: wow im so dumb thanks anyway however when i do that i get this error: ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Comment: Then you need to remove the b from wb, wb means write binary, but you are not reading as binary, but in utf 8

Comment: oh okay thanks ill do more research